# Can I use (two-dot) range notation for revisions in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I want to show only the revisions of a branch since the fork from the master.

At the git bash I can do the following:
`git log master..mybranch`

Can I do the same in TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the log dialog from command line using `tortoisegitproc /command:log /range:master..mybranch`.

It is also possible to get this using the GUI: In LogDialog click on the branch indicator in the upper left. Then select the two branches/refs you want to see and click on OK. Here a context menu appears where you can select **"master..mybranch"**. See:

[image]

Or you can right click on the selected branches, and here is also a **"Show log of master..mybranch"** item in context menu. See:
[image]
It opens a **NEW** Log Message dialog for **"master..mybranch"**.